# Can we change the date format in query?

Tags: soql

SFDC always gives a format YYYY-MM-DD on querying the date field. Is there any function or some formatting I can put in the query to change the format of the date. ?

`Select somefunction (date__c) from Customobject__c` ..

Something like this, or format I can provide in query itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing [Dynamic SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm), then yes, you could use a custom method to process date literal into the required string format.

Otherwise you are limited to the built in [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm), [Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), or creating a formula field to do the Date conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I  am making query from a Java program and hitting standard REST query URL.

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal In that case you could create a method in Java to convert the value to a native Date (or what ever it is that Java uses to represent a Date and Time). Remember the the API passes UTC values.